# I have string to datetime conversion error

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have this piece of code which results some statistics based on the date (Month)

```
var customersList = customerDatesBLL.GetAll()
  .Where(cust => cust.CaseDate != null)
  .GroupBy(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.CaseDate,"dd/MM/yyyy",null).Month)
  .Select(c => new { 
    SumOfCustomer = c.Count(), 
    mount = int.Parse(c.Select(x => (DateTime.ParseExact(x.CaseDate,
"dd/MM/yyyy", null)).Month.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()) 
  })
  .ToList();
```

That code always results a `FormatException`:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Raw Data:[dates from database in dd/mm/yyyy format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW8A0.jpg)

Comment: Show us your raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in parsing the `CaseDate` which might be caused by a couple of things:

1- `CaseDate`s are not correct string format they might be like "2/10/2016"
 this causes error parsing as "dd/MM/yyyy"

2- Culture might be culprit here since separators in date are depending on them. You can try

```
DateTime.ParseExact(c.CaseDate,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Check if these helped you if not try to parse the dates in an out standing loop so that the runtime error is generated at the exact `CaseDate` that causes the problem and post that here.

Comment: CaseDate is like "2/10/2016" yes

Comment: that's why I'm using `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `DateTime.Parse `

Comment: @moaatazaamer: And that's exactly why you _shouldn't_ use `ParseExact`. In your current pattern you need a leading zero: "02/10/2016". Read the answer carefully, it might help you out.

Comment: @sefe I've already added a piece of my  raw data up there please check it but the problem still the same

Comment: @moaatazaamer: The answer has two parts. And you should check, it's your problem...

Comment: @moaatazaamer I looked at your data. What is the final Null? It isn't in your data right?

Comment: @Emad just a raw in the table with no data, I've neglected all null values in the code already

Comment: Did you used the second method I sent? Also equal to that is you escape your slashes like this: `"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"`

Comment: @Emad I've Evaluated the dates in a separate loop and I've noticed that the first date ("30/10/2016") passes, but in the second date (4/4/2016) it throw the exception! I've tried to change the date format to "d/M/yyy" but the same result appears !

Comment: You can't do that. As safe said you shouldn't use `ParseExact` if your data is not "Exact". You shouldn't have string like "4/4/2016" but rather "04/04/2016". Use normal DateTime.Parse and you'll be fine. Trust me :)

Comment: @Emad Also I used this Format: "dd'\'/MM'\'/yyyy" but the same result !